# Finding the average when two infos on averages are given

Tags: statistics, average

This is one competitive exam's question. Can someone give me an easy explanation on how to solve this problem?

**Question**

Sam earned a `$2000` commision on a big sale, raising his average commission by `$100`. If Sam's new average commission is $900, how many sales has he made?

I tries to use the avg formula,

```
Sum of N numbers = avg X Number of Terms
```

But I am not quite getting it

Comment: How is this possible? You are saying his average has increased by \$100 yet his new average is \$100 which means his original average is \$0.

Comment: Agree with Jeevan.  Please recheck the given problem.

Comment: @JeevanDevaranjan I am so sorry..you r right, its $900 the new average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of sales he has now made.  Before the last sale he had made $n-1$ sales with an average commission of $800$ dollars, so his total commission was $800(n-1)$ dollars.  He has now made $n$ sales at an average of $900$ dollars, total $900n$ dollars.  Since the difference is his latest $2000$ dollar commission,
$$900n=800(n-1)+2000\ .$$
See if you can solve this.

Comment: thanx..I got it, its 12